# How Earth's Gravity is more powerful than its centrifugal force?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, gravity, forces, newtonian-gravity

How Earth's Gravity more powerful than centrifugal force?

> The earth spins all the time but we are not holding onto something to avoid drifting off in space cause of the centrifugal force.

Comment: Well, it is. Is there any particular reason why it shouldn't be?

Comment: This line of reasoning allows the earth to spin more slowly (reducing the centrifugal force to near zero) but sets an upper limit to how fast it can spin.  What would be the length of a day if the centrifugal force at the equator equaled $g$?  In that case, if you ran East, you would launch into orbit.

Answer (score 4):

Because the centripetal force due to the rotation in small compared with that of gravity. A calculation for Earth at the equator $(\omega = 2\pi/86164$ seconds, $r = 6378100$ meters) shows that an object experiences a centrifugal force equal to approximately 1/289 of standard gravity